# how to create directory in the desktop of the centos 7

Tags: linux, directory, desktop

I am using CentOS 7. Now I need to create a directory as "infomation" in the desktop of the centos. What is the right command for that?

Comment: `mkdir ~/Desktop/directory`

Comment: good it is working

Comment: it is working good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got `mkdir` command which allows you to create a directory, it is a powerfull command, i suggest you to get a look on the man page of mkdir (by typing `man mkdir` in a terminal).

In order to create a text file, you got plenty of choices, the one i prefere is to type `the.name.of.your.favourite.text.editor the.path.and.name.of.your.file`

I don't use centos so i don't know which text editors are installed by default. Vim is a very powerfull text editor that is installed on every (to my knowledge) linux distro but i suggest you to keep a mind map of this editor with you for the starting ([here](http://www.formation-lpi.com/IMG/pdf/103.8-vi.pdf) is one but it is in french... google should have one in your language...)
There probably is also nano installed by default, maybe easier for starting but i prefere Vi because it is everywhere and it is not so difficult to use in my opinion despite what a lot of users say.

I highly recommend you to have a look on tutorial books (i'm a debian and manjaro user so i read the [debian's handbook](https://debian-handbook.info/) which is very well written maybe an equivalent exist for centos)
But when you know how to survive one distro, you got the idea and it is just some details that change in the other ones.

well, good luck in this wonderful world!